# .submit() not passing the data to php

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#saveform').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var emailval = $("#e_id").val();
        $.post('chk_unique_email.php', { 'email': emailval }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data == 'exists') {
                $('#dispmessg').html('');
                $('#dispmessg').html("This email id already exists.</br>");
                // return false;
            }
            else {
                $("#reg").submit();
            }   
        });     
    });
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="post" action="register.php"  name="reg" id="reg">
    <input class="form-control" id="e_id" type="email" name="email"  autofocus required/>
    <p id="dispmessg" style="color: red;"></p>
    <button id="saveform" class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit"  name="bsubmit"   >Sign Up </button>
```

The uniqueness of the email id is being checked, but after correcting it or if the email id is unique the form shows error in submission where the post variables don't work in PHP.

Comment: you did close off `</form>`, right?

Comment: look at your console and use error reporting. There's also no php here

Comment: try with button `type="button"`. also check what @Fred-ii- mentioned

Comment: you have `$.post('chk_unique_email.php'` yet doing `action="register.php"`. So, something failed.

Comment: yes,i have closed all the tags . Tried console too. The problem is with after submission.. When i tried this without checking for the uniqueness it was working fine, after adding the jquery is when this happens.

Comment: What do you see if you put var_dump($_POST);die(); at the top of register.php?

Comment: NULL. nothing seems to get passed to register.php